# I am using chip view in android using kotlin. I need to implement clickk function

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Just like button I used setOnClickListener on each chip view. But it isn't working.
I am sorry if this is easy to answer, but I'm new to android. so please do help me.
My xml file is looking fine. This is the fragment code.

override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

```
     val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
     setHasOptionsMenu(true)
     byName = view.findViewById(R.id.byName)
     byPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.byPrice) if(Connection().checkConnectivity(activity as Context)) {

        no_net.visibility = View.GONE
        appbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val q = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity as Context)
        val url = "http://13.235.250.119/v2/restaurants/fetch_result/"
        try{
            progress_bar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val jsonreq = object : JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,url,null,
                Response.Listener {
                    if(it.getJSONObject("data").getBoolean("success")){
                        list = arrayListOf<DataList>()
                        val data = it.getJSONObject("data").getJSONArray("data")
                        for(i in 0 until data.length()){
                            list.add(
                                DataList(
                                    data.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"),
                                    data.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"),
                                    data.getJSONObject(i).getString("rating"),
                                    data.getJSONObject(i).getString("cost_for_one"),
                                    data.getJSONObject(i).getString("image_url")
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        recl_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
                        recl_view.adapter = MainAdapter(activity ?: return@Listener,list)
                        progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                },
                Response.ErrorListener {
                    appbar.visibility = View.GONE
                    progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
                    Toast.makeText(activity as Context,"Please Try Again Later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }){
                override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                    headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
                    headers["token"] = "c3acf1e14c21f9"
                    return headers
                }
            }
            q.add(jsonreq)
        }catch (e: Exception){
            appbar.visibility = View.GONE
            progress_bar.visibility = View.GONE
            Toast.makeText(activity as Context,"Please Try Again Later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
    else{
        appbar.visibility = View.GONE
        Toast.makeText(activity as Context,"Please Check your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        no_net.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    var ratingCompName = Comparator<DataList> { item1, item2 ->
        if (item1.name.compareTo(item2.name, true) == 0) {
            item1.rating.compareTo(item2.rating, true)

        } else {

            item1.name.compareTo(item2.name, true)

        }

    }
    var ratingComprating = Comparator<DataList> { item1, item2 ->
        if (item1.rating.compareTo(item2.rating, true) == 0) {
            item1.name.compareTo(item2.name, true)

        } else {

            item1.rating.compareTo(item2.rating, true)

        }

    }
    var ratingCompPrice = Comparator<DataList> { item1, item2 ->
        if (item1.cost_for_one.compareTo(item2.cost_for_one, true) == 0) {
            item1.rating.compareTo(item2.rating, true)

        } else {

            item1.cost_for_one.compareTo(item2.cost_for_one, true)

        }

    }

    byName.setOnClickListener {
        Collections.sort(list, ratingCompName)
        recl_view.adapter = MainAdapter(activity as Context, list)

        (recl_view.adapter as MainAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
    byRating.setOnClickListener {
        Collections.sort(list, ratingComprating)
        recl_view.adapter = MainAdapter(activity as Context, list)

        (recl_view.adapter as MainAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()



    }
```

Comment: Check if the chip object (byName) is properly initialized or not.

Comment: "view.findViewById(R.id.byName)" must not be null, this is what error shows after initializing. @AtickFaisal

Comment: can you try with just simple click.  byName.setOnClickListener {
      Toast.makeText(this,"click here",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    } its working or not

Comment: No, it isn't working. The same error is shown. @DharmenderManral

Comment: are you sure layout name is correct where you have add chip R.layout.fragment_main

Comment: Got it. Sorry, instead of main_fragment I was doing it in main_activity..lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the following code it will help you.

```
      //activity xml
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="UserName"
    android:id="@+id/userNameChip"/></LinearLayout>


 //Activity code
  class TestActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var userNameChip: Chip
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)
    userNameChip = findViewById(R.id.userNameChip)
    userNameChip.setOnClickListener { view ->
        val defaultUser: String = (view as Chip).text.toString()
        Toast.makeText(this,defaultUser,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: The app is crashing without any error message @DharmenderManral

Comment: select error instead of verbose in logcat tab and paste here what is the exact error.

Comment: view.findViewById(R.id.byName) must not be null. This is the error shown

Comment: I have included it

Comment: xml looking fine add also show your fragment onCreate and onViewCreated code